# win32 without mouse, how to assign keyboard shortcuts to buttons

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, wine

I wrote a simple win32 GUI application with buttons and other controls, in pure C, no MFC. I want to make it more accessible for those who can not use mouse.

1. First, my example code does not respond to `Tab` key to move focus from one button to another. I can press UI button using mouse, than it becomes focused and i can activate button using `Space-bar`, but i can't move focus to other buttons using `Tab` or `Shift+Tab`. How can i fix this?
2. I want to assign keyboard cues (little underscores) to buttons, so user can use keyboard shortcuts to activate buttons.

I have google it around, but answers are hard googleable, so i need someone to point me to some documentation. A little piece of code would be very helpful.

Here is the code i have. I compile and run it on Linux using WINE + TinyCC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* Yeres distributed forums node v0001 */

/* compile: wine tcc_win/tcc/tcc.exe win_yeres */


HWND status_text_hwnd = NULL;
HWND shutdown_hs_button_hwnd = NULL;

unsigned int button_height = 26;
unsigned int window_length = 400;
#define V_BUTTON_PADDING 2

int tor_running = 0;
int select_running = 0;


#include "yeres_bind.c"
#include "win_yeres_w1_proc.c"


int APIENTRY WinMain(
        HINSTANCE hInstance,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPSTR lpCmdLine,
        int nCmdShow
        ) {

  MSG msg;
  WNDCLASS wc;
  HWND hwnd;

  printf("\n  **  YERES v0001  **\n\n");


  // Fill in window class structure with parameters that describe
  // the main window.

  ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof wc);
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
  wc.lpszClassName = "yeres_wcl";
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = (WNDPROC)w1_proc;
  wc.style         = CS_DBLCLKS|CS_VREDRAW|CS_HREDRAW;
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 0);
  wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_EXCLAMATION);
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

  if (FALSE == RegisterClass(&wc)) return 0;

  RECT client_rect;
  client_rect.left = 0;
  client_rect.top = 0;
  client_rect.right = window_length;
  client_rect.bottom = 500;

  /* calculate window size from known client area size */
  if (0 == AdjustWindowRect(&client_rect, wc.style, 0)) return 0;

  // create main window
  hwnd = CreateWindow(
    "yeres_wcl",
    "YERES control panel",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
    30,
    30,
    client_rect.right,   //CW_USEDEFAULT
    client_rect.bottom,
    0,
    0,
    hInstance,
    0);

  if (NULL == hwnd) return 0;

  // Main message loop:
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  return msg.wParam;
}
```

```
#define ID_TOR_CONTROL_PORT 1
#define ID_BIND 2
#define ID_UNBIND 3
#define ID_TOR_SHUTDOWN_HS 4
#define ID_PORT_NUM 5
#define ID_QUIT 6


LRESULT CALLBACK w1_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

  int y = 4;
  int x;
  RECT rc;
  switch (message) {

    case WM_CREATE:

    ZeroMemory(&rc, sizeof(rc));
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    if (rc.right) window_length = rc.right - rc.left;

    status_text_hwnd = CreateWindow("Static",
                "** YERES v0001 **\n\nPress 'Bind to localhost'..",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER,
                3, y, window_length, (button_height * 3),
                hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
    y += button_height * 3;

    x = 2;
    CreateWindow("Static", "Port:",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER,
                x, y, 60, button_height,
                hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
    x += 60;
    /* editable field here */
    CreateWindow("Edit", "19407", 
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
                x, y, 90, button_height, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_PORT_NUM,
                NULL, NULL);
    x += 120;

    CreateWindow("Button", "Bind to localhost",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                x, y, 140, button_height,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BIND, NULL, NULL);
    x += 140;
    CreateWindow("Button", "Unbind",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                x, y, window_length - 2 - x, button_height,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_UNBIND, NULL, NULL);

    y += button_height + V_BUTTON_PADDING;

    CreateWindow("Button", "Use tor control port to start HiddenService",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                2, y, window_length - 4, button_height,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TOR_CONTROL_PORT, NULL, NULL);
    y += button_height + V_BUTTON_PADDING;

    shutdown_hs_button_hwnd = CreateWindow("Button", "Shutdown HiddenService",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                2, y, window_length - 4, button_height,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TOR_SHUTDOWN_HS, NULL, NULL);
    EnableWindow(shutdown_hs_button_hwnd, 0); /* inactive button */
    y += button_height + V_BUTTON_PADDING;

    CreateWindow("Button", "Shutdown EVERYTHING and QUIT",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                2, y, window_length - 4, button_height,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
    y += button_height + V_BUTTON_PADDING;

    break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    if (!tor_running && !select_running) PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;


    case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
      case ID_BIND:
      yeres_bind();
      break;

      case ID_QUIT:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;

      default: DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;

    default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);

  };
  return 0;
};
```

P.S. Sorry my bad English :)

Comment: Everything you need to know to implement a reliable keyboard interface can be found at Raymond Chen's blog. The following entries are immediately relevant: [Using the TAB key to navigate in non-dialogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031021-00/?p=42083); [Using the TAB key to navigate in non-dialogs, redux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131009-00/?p=2983); [If I have a modeless dialog box with custom accelerators, which should I call first: IsDialogMessage or TranslateAccelerator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160818-00/?p=94115).

Comment: OK, tab key now works. But it is unclear how to add mnemonic to the button. If i create accelerator table, will user see the underlined letter in button label? How can i configure, which letter gets underlined?

Comment: Add ampersand before mnemonic letter in button text. `Save`->`&Save`, `More`->`Mo&re`.

Comment: Do you need to underline all button text?

Comment: Strive Sun, no, just one shortcut letter. All right, i will try all variants and post my piece of code once thing will be ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple. In main message processing loop, i call `IsDialogMessage()` with proper `HWND`. Then, if this function returns zero, i call normal TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage functions. Here is code:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
  if(!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  };

  yeres_select(); /* scan incoming connections on sockets using select(), activated by timer and/or other messages */

}
```

Every button in the window has bit `WS_TABSTOP` set, so when i press `Tab`, `IsDialogMessage()` will catch message and move focus to the next button. Editable also can be selected this way.

`WS_GROUP` didn't work for me. In theory it should allow me to navigate using arrow keys. I have placed `WS_GROUP` bit in first button.

```
CreateWindow("Button", "&Bind to localhost",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP,
            x, y, 140, button_height,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BIND, NULL, NULL);
```

Ampersand mnemonics work even without `TranslateAccelerator()` call, just put it into label text `"&Bind to localhost"`, and button can be activated using `Alt+B` or so. It is not case-sensitive.

I did not check it on Windows, but i think if it works in WINE it should be OK.